# Formula IF with territory field / salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning, if

Good afternoon,

**I want to display "East", if territories are:**
New England

Northeast

Mid-Atlantic

Southeast

Midwest

Hearthland

**I want to display "West", if territories aren't these values.**

BELOW MY FORMULA

```
IF(OR(Account.Territory = "New England", Account.Territory = "Northeast", Account.Territory = "Mid-Atlantic", Account.Territory = "Southeast", Account.Territory = "Midwest", Account.Territory = "Heartland"), "East", "West")
```

**But, I've got this error:** "Error: Field Account.Territory doesn't exist."

Can  you solve my problem?

Comment: I don't think Territory is exposed like that. There is an idea about it here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cJNpAAM

Comment: Ok, i check the post. The problem is: I don`t know what is Query AccountShare object, and how to create it.